# List of user names and emails

Tags: views, 7

I have a role called "Secretary" and I would like for the role to be able to access a "view" with a list of usernames and emails. What's the easiest way to do this?

I know how to let only the secretary have access to the page, and I have the views module installed. But I'm not that good with it yet. Any ideas?

Comment: "I know how to let only the secretary have access to the page": so what's your problem?

Comment: I guess everyone concentrated on the permissions part of the question. I can't figure out how to create a page of user names and emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple - on your view, select "Page Settings" -> "Access: Permission" then chose "Role" and select your "Secretary" role.

Comment: My question was basically how to create a view, and not how to set access to the view. Bad communication on my part I guess. Either way, I'll select this as correct.